# Construction of the Gaussian white noise on the projective space?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stochastic-processes, projective-geometry

I would like to know if there is a natural notion of Gaussian white noise that has been defined on the real projective space $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n$ of dimension $n$.

My impression is that it is doable, for instance as a limit of homogeneous polynomial functions of increasing degree, but I could not find such a construction.

Comment: What properties should this notion have, in your opinion?

Answer (score 1):

This is a well investigated issue in probability.   To any Riemann metric on $\mathbb{RP}^n$ you can  canonically associate  a Gaussian white noise.  Have a look at  the beautiful book of Gelfand and Vilenkin "*Generalized Functions, vol. 4: Applications of Harmonic Analysis*".

The white noise is a generalized process with independent values at every point.